# Select the Hebrew equivalent of SQL Server DateTime columns

Tags: datetime, azure-sql-database, hebrew

If I have a table of Gregorian birth dates stored in a `DateTime` column, how can I, given today's Hebrew date, determine if someone has a Hebrew birthday today?

I need to somehow select the equivalent Hebrew month and day of the Gregorian date stored in the table.

Unfortunately

```
where month(BirthDate) = x and day(BirthDate) = y
```

returns the Gregorian values and not the Hebrew values.

I need month(BirthDate) to return the Hebrew value

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

According my experience, there isn't any functions support convert Gregorian `Datetime` to Hebrew date directly in Azure SQL database or SQL server.

Any suggestions, you can learn from [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) and [Hebrew calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar), try to encode the convert script or function by yourself.

The simplest way is that, since you have given the Hebrew date, you can convert it to Gregorian Date with so many tools from the internet, such as: [Convert from Hebrew to Gregorian date](https://www.hebcal.com/converter/?gd=8&gm=1&gy=2020&g2h=1).
[image]

Then you can get the value of x(month) and y(day).

Hope this helps.

Comment: since the Gregorian date corresponding to the Hebrew date changes every year. given today's date I have no way of knowing if it is someone's birthday unless I also know the year year the person was born. considering that i do have the Gregorian birthday and year, i could calculate that, but that would mean creating a cursor and going through every row in the DB

Comment: case in point: Tue, 8 January 2019 = 2nd of Sh'vat, 5779. last year the same Gregorian date was even in a different Hebrew month

Comment: and the fact that Hebrew leap years add an entire month complicates this. as the 7th month in most years, Nisan, is the 8th month in a leap year.